# Trying to create a discord bot using js getting errors

Tags: javascript, json

hello I am following the tutorial on digitaltrends site on how to create a discord bot getting a few errors

the tutorial I followed is on  https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/

Errors when trying to complile and download the necessary dependencies are

```
**C:\discordbots>npm install discord.io winston -save**
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! file C:\discordbots\package.json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse json
npm ERR! JSON.parse Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 3 while parsing near '{
npm ERR! JSON.parse “name”: “PUAGirls-bo...'
npm ERR! JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\eugen\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-09T21_06_55_511Z-debug.log

**C:\discordbots>npm install discord.io winston -save**
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\discordbots\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\discordbots\package.json'
npm WARN discordbots No description
npm WARN discordbots No repository field.
npm WARN discordbots No README data
npm WARN discordbots No license field.

+ winston@3.2.1
+ discord.io@2.5.3
added 43 packages from 35 contributors and audited 49 packages in 25.961s
found 0 vulnerabilities


**C:\discordbots>npm install https://github.com/woor/discord.io/tarball/gateway_v6**
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\discordbots\package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\discordbots\package.json'
npm WARN discordbots No description
npm WARN discordbots No repository field.
npm WARN discordbots No README data
npm WARN discordbots No license field.

+ discord.io@2.5.3
updated 1 package and audited 144 packages in 6.168s
found 0 vulnerabilities


C:\discordbots>node bot.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1193
    throw err;
    ^

SyntaxError: C:\discordbots\auth.json: Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 3
at parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.Module._extensions..json (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1190:22)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\discordbots\bot.js:3:12)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
```

END ERRORS

how can I sort this out ? I have completed the necessary .json files as well but the main auth.json file has my client id in it don't really want that given out

The JavaScript code for the bot is

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, 
{
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';
// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});
bot.on('ready', function (evt) {
    logger.info('Connected');
    logger.info('Logged in as: ');
    logger.info(bot.username + ' - (' + bot.id + ')');
});
bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
// Our bot needs to know if it will execute a command
// It will listen for messages that will start with `!`
if (message.substring(0, 1) == '!') {
    var args = message.substring(1).split(' ');
    var cmd = args[0];

    args = args.splice(1);
    switch(cmd) {
        // !lucy
        case 'lucy':
            bot.sendMessage({
                to: channelID,
                message: 'Whatever you do DO NOT buy this girl perfume'
            });
        break;
        // Just add any case commands if you want to..
     }
 }
});
```

I have 36 more of these commands to do and possibly more

Comment: Seems like you need to `npm init` first

Comment: Looks like you have Smart Quotes in there, not regular quotes. Open the file in Notepad++, VSCode, or anything but Microsoft Office products basically and replace anything double-quote-like with normal double quotes.

Comment: Seems like there is a problem with your `auth.json` file.

Comment: Solved it was problems with the inverted commas in the json files